# Detect user domain in Asp.net Form Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, form-authentication

a client sent a request to an Asp.net web application base on a Form authentication. How can i get its active Directory's Username of logged on client  ?

the client and the web application are both in the same Domain.

Answer (score 0):

in my intranet application i use something like this :

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Authenticate the user, with windows auth(and domain) 
        /// If that fails then authenticate with forms
        /// If that fails...well, go to hell
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected void loginControl_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) {

            //First try the windows login (domain+username / password)
            Logging.IntranetLogger.LogIntranetActionInfo(Logging.IntranetLogConst.Logging, Logging.IntranetLogConst.UserTryToLoggIn, loginControl.UserName);

            string domainName = GetDomainName(loginControl.UserName); // Extract domain name 
            //form provide DomainUsername e.g Domainname\Username
            string userName = GetUsername(loginControl.UserName);  // Extract user name 
            //from provided DomainUsername e.g Domainname\Username
            IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;

            //userName, domainName and Password parameters are very obvious.
            //dwLogonType (3rd parameter): 
            //    I used LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, This logon type is 
            //    intended for users who will be interactively using the computer, 
            //    such as a user being logged on by a terminal server, remote shell, 
            //    or similar process. 
            //    This logon type has the additional expense of caching 
            //    logon information for disconnected operations.
            //    For more details about this parameter please see 
            //    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(VS.85).aspx
            //dwLogonProvider (4th parameter) :
            //    I used LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAUL, This provider use the standard 
            //    logon provider for the system. 
            //    The default security provider is negotiate, unless you pass 
            //    NULL for the domain name and the user name is not in UPN format. 
            //    In this case, the default provider is NTLM. For more details 
            //    about this parameter please see 
            //    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(VS.85).aspx
            //phToken (5th parameter):
            //    A pointer to a handle variable that receives a handle to a 
            //    token that represents the specified user. We can use this handler 
            //    for impersonation purpose. 


            //authenticate with the inputed 
            bool windowsLoginResult = LogonUser(userName, domainName, loginControl.Password, 2, 0, ref token);}



 [DllImport("ADVAPI32.dll", EntryPoint = "LogonUserW", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

 public static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);
```

the code is not mine, it is taken from somewhere on codeproject, i am sorry i don't remember exactly where from and the author

Comment: this is not the answer i am looking for